# Can I use SFP+ like just data cable?

Tags: xilinx, transceiver

i'm using zc706 (xilinx) eval board.
I want to connect ZC706 and custom board for transcevier.
The zc706 board has SMA, SFP+ connector for GTH trancevier.
Can I use SFP connector for just cable with using only tx/rx pin like figure below (molex 74441-0010)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use an SFP+ passive DAC (direct attach cable). Then you don't need power or anything like that. They will be designed for Ethernet, so be careful if you deviate too much from Ethernet signaling.

Comment: thanks for reply!

Comment: Hm, SFP+ DAC are not "designed for ethernet" as in the ethernet that you have on twisted pair – these are twinax cabling, probably 50Ω wave impedance per core, and there's both passive and active cables without and with amplifiers / electronic receivers at each end!

Comment: I just searched for SFP+ DAC, and all the results on the first two pages were talking about 10G Ethernet. So yes, while it's just a cable that will work for lots of different things, I'd say they were definitely designed for Ethernet usage. Active DAC probably won't work in this case because they likely need power from the connector and maybe some control signals as well.